# Convert/translate tbl lib idl

Tags: c#, windows-ce

This might be a stupid question.

I have a lib file cemapi.lib that allows c++ devs to use mapi on winCE.

What i need is a tlb file so i can reference this in c#. Normally i would find the IDL and use midl to make a tlb but guess what there is no IDL.

So is there a way to get

lib to tlb 
lib to Idl

thanks

Answer (score 1):

I do not believe there is a way to convert a plain old .lib file into a TLB.  LIB files are the minimum needed by the C++ compiler / linker for linking into a larger DLL or EXE.  It does not contain metadata, so to speak, and hence can't be used to create a TLB or IDL file.

You may have to hand code the interfaces into your C# application.